# How to prevent double from rounding up to two decimal

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate a percentage(9% tax) of a item

```
double amount = 55.4;
double total = amount * 0.09;

System.out.printf ("%f \n", total);
System.out.printf ("%.2f \n", total);
```

Returns

4.986000

4.99

How do I make it return 4.98?

Thanks!

Comment: `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", Math.floor(total * 100) / 100.0);`

Comment: Wow, why does it work? And is there a way to change it at the variable level instead of the print level?

Comment: Take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/4210091

Comment: For financial values us bigDecimal instaed

Answer (score 2):

Use BigDecimal instead of double.

double is floating point, which cannot accurately represent all fractional amounts, hence the "rounding" problem that you are.experiencing.

BigDecimal is arbitrary-precision, and so doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chop off the thousands place multiple your total by 100 and cast it to an int, then divide it by 100 and cast it to a double:

```
double amount = 55.4;
double total = amount * 0.09;
int truncated = (int) (total * 100);
double val = truncated * .01;

System.out.printf("%.2f\n", val);
```

This will give you:
    4.98

This can also be done with

```
double val = Math.floor(total * 100) / 100;
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", val);
```